# Update set with columns depending on another

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Im trying to set column values, for example `area` then use this `area` column value in the following set, for example `area * somecolumn`. When I do this it seems that `area` hasnt been set yet. Do I need to do something for postgres to register/understand/commit for the next set statement to work? Or should this work?

```
update table1 t1
set
    area = something;
    --update/commit/save edits/?

update table1 t1
set
    volume = area * col1 #I belive area hasnt been set yet so volume become NULL. But when I look at the table afterwards, area has a value

and many more...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries should do what you intend, provide that "something" and `col1`  are not `null`.

However you can easily do what you want with a single statement:

```
update table1 t1
set area = $1, volume = $1 * col1
```

Comment: Nice, then I must be doing somehing else wrong, I will try and find out. What is the dollar sign for/called?

Comment: @BERA: that's a bind parameter, that represents the value you want to pass to the query (you called that "something" in your question).

Comment: The dollar sign is used to reference the input parameters in their respective order.

Comment: Thanks! Now I found the error. I did something like `1-30/100` on the  right-hand side of the equal sign and expected it to return a decimal number, but it returns 1. `1-30/100::real` fixed it

Comment: @BERA: I see. That's called integer division.Note: I would recommend using an exact datatype (`numeric`, `decimal`) rather than `real`, which is inexact.

Comment: Is `1-25/100::numeric` equal to `1::numeric-25::numeric/100::numeric`. They give the same results. I mean is it enough that one of the "inputs" are real?

Comment: @BERA: yes. If there is one numeric operand, the whole operation is performed in numeric context.